# QML can't hide Rectangle

Tags: c++, qml

I have a Window containing what I called a Page - a Rectangle the size of the main window:

```qml
LoginWindow {
    id: loginWindow
}

SelectionWindow {
    id: selectionWindow
}

ServiceWindow {
    id: serviceWindow
}

ConfirmWindow {
    id: confirmWindow
}

IssueWindow {
    id: issueWindow
}
```

Each *Window here is an element inheriting from Page.

Now I can jump between different Page elements setting their visibility. Only one Page can be visible at a time. The last Page is IssueWindow and from there I want to switch back to LoginWindow and logout the user.

From C++ I emit a signal issueFinished and in MainWindow I have this code:

```qml
    onIssueFinished: {
        // This line won't hide the Page
        issueWindow.visible = false;

        loginHandle.logout();
    }
```

As noted in the comment, the Page element just won't hide, while other elements will change their visibility. I am using GammaRay to see the changes and everything works, just hiding the issueWindow doesn't. Also when printing the issueWindow.visible to console, it's false.

Comment: Why don't you use a `Loader`?

Comment: @user2436719: The loader would kill the instances. However it might be imperative to keep the instances, for having no stateless view, or having complex views that would take to much time to reinstanciate. If you have enough memory at hand it gives a more reactive feeling, if you do not have to wait to reinstanciate a page every time you switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue was actually incorrect order of switching visibility and firing signals and responding to them.

Answer (score 0):

Use [opacity](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#opacity-prop) instead of visibility, and bind one method on opacity change which handle the enabled and disabled state like.

```
onIssueFinished: {
        // This line won't hide the Page
        issueWindow.opacity = 0.0;

        loginHandle.logout();
    }

IssueWindow {
    id: issueWindow

    onOpacityChanged: {
        enabled = ( opacity === 1.0)
    }
}
```

You need to implement opacity change in all the windows. 
And set the opacity for all other windows.

Or you can use [stack view](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-stackview.html) or [swipe view](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.7/qml-qtquick-controls2-swipeview.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though this didn't solve the problem. What's the benefit of using opacity over visible?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure only one Page is visible, you might use an index.
You set the visibility to:

```
visible: (selected == thisPageIdentifier)
```

With this you make sure, only the page with the corresponding pageIdentifyer is visible, and you don't have to throw around multiple signals to show and hide.
When a new page shall become visible, just set the `selected` property to the corresponding identifier (int or string or what ever) and the other pages turn invisible.
This should increase scalability as you do not have new signals to handle in all the other pages, if you decide to add a new page once. You only need to make sure, the identifier is unique.

Your example code adjusted to this:

```
Item {
    property int selection: 0
    LoginWindow {
        id: loginWindow
        visible: (selection === 0)
    }

    SelectionWindow {
        id: selectionWindow
        visible: (selection === 1)
    }

    ServiceWindow {
        id: serviceWindow
        visible: (selection === 2)
    }

    ConfirmWindow {
        id: confirmWindow
        visible: (selection === 3)
    }

    IssueWindow {
        id: issueWindow
        visible: (selection === 4)
    }
}
```